# How to design time series measurements (tables)

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I am using a time series database (InfluxDB) and I am trying to understand how to design a measurement (table).
My background is using relational database where it is common to join tables.
In my current project we are writing different sensor values like (temperature and pressure) for many 
vehicles to a measurement along with associated identifiers so that we know the specific details of 
the each value we measure.

```
Measurement: Sensor_Trans
Tags: time, vehicleId, sensorId
Fields: value (temperature or pressure)
```

Later when I want to use these values, I need addtional details about the specific values.
Note: that I currently have 20+ unique tags for each sensor measurement like:
unit of measure, size of vehicle, senor description, etc.

For example: I want to know the engine pressure in Kpa for all cars with four doors.

For example: I want to know the exhaust temperature in degrees C for truck 89.

I'd like to know what is concidered best practise when designing time series measurements (tables)?

1- Do I add more tags that provide the addition inforation directly to the measurement?

2- Do I keep the Vehicle and Sensor definitions in a relational table and join in code?

3- Other?

Answer (score 2):

**1-Do I add more tags that provide the additional information directly to the measurement?** Yes you can do that but also keep in mind adding more tags also consume more memory. Please refer the system requirements in the following link
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/guides/hardware_sizing/

**2- Do I keep the Vehicle and Sensor definitions in a relational table and join in code?** No need if you implement the above, you can design a relation DB table for your entire need instead ok keeping two different databases.